# Why we return max({count,v1,v2}) in Longest Common Substring

Tags: string, dynamic-programming

why we return max({count,v1,v2}) in longest common substring as i did the longest common subsequence first then did the longest common substring , but get confused , as in longest common subsequence if x[n-1] == y[m-1] then i return but in case of longest common substring i didn't return value instead i wait for other 2 recursion calls then return the max. I m really confused.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the LC-Subsequence algorithm, we increase the count in the caller since the aggregation of the counts can happen in levels down the tree that do not necessarily need to be the immediate child of that tree - in other words, we can skip levels till we find the next match and the count is an aggregation of these levels where we found a match. Here we don't look for discontinuation.

```
ex: x: a,b,c,d,e,f
    y: a,b,f,c,e
    lc-subsequence: a,b,c,e
    max: 4
here you can jump from b -> c in string y. Similarly, c -> e in string x.
```

But in the case of the LC-Substring, we pass in the count to the next level since we want to increase the count if and only if we have a match at the immediate next level. That is, here we look for discontinuation.

```
 ex: x: a,b,c,d,e,f
        y: a,b,f,c,e
        lc-substring: a,b | c | e 
        max: 2
here you can't jump from b -> c in string y and and c->e in string x respectively.
```

Therefore, count represent the string that matches exactly in both strings x and y. That's why you take max of (count,v1,v2)

Comment: Thank-you, For the solution. Understood Completely.